# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We are using Reporting Service(SSRS 2008) webservice(ReportingService2005.asmx, ReportingExecutionService2005.asmx) to export/Render the report into PDF format from Windows application. When exporting the huge amount of data contain report(Upto 10MB), then we are getting exception as "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive". Small amount of data contain reports are working properly.

Same reports are working properly in our development environmnet. This issue we are getting in our production environment.

> Exception Details:
>
> System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)    at
>   ReportWebReference.ReportingService.Render(String
>   Report, String Format, String
>   HistoryID, String DeviceInfo,
>   ParameterValue[] Parameters,
>   DataSourceCredentials[] Credentials,
>   String ShowHideToggle, String&
>   Encoding, String& MimeType,
>   ParameterValue[]& ParametersUsed,
>   Warning[]& Warnings, String[]&
>   StreamIds)

Even though Reporting Service time out set as "Infinite" we are facing the issue.

To resolve this isuue, Do we need to change any configuration settings in the reporting server/IIS?..

Comment: see this solution - [http://iwillsharemypoint.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/underlying-connection-was-closed.html](http://iwillsharemypoint.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/underlying-connection-was-closed.html) it a proxy problem

Answer (score 1):

You will probably get more information about the error by examining the log files on the reporting server.

[Reporting Services Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157403.aspx)